# Redefinição de senha laravel

Tags: laravel

Bom dia pessoal,
Sou iniciante no laravel, estou com o seguinte problema:
Estou usando template AdminLTE, não sei se isso tem algo haver com o problema.
Acredito ter feito todas as configurações necessárias para a recuperação de senha funcionar. Configurei o arquivo .env, etc...

No site, ao clicar em "Esqueci minha senha" ele redireciona para rota "/password/reset" então informo o e-mail e a senha e clico em enviar link. Até essa parte tudo funciona bem, o e-mail com o link é enviado, todo em inglês.

Porém, ao clicar no link do email de recuperação de senha ele vai para a rota "login" e não para a rota onde seria possível cadastrar uma nova senha.

Reparei que no banco de dados o token de recuperação de senha parece estar sendo gravado de forma correta.
Reparei, também, que nos arquivos gerados pelo AdminLTE existe a view reset.blade.php, acredito que o redirecionamento deveria ser para essa view. Não sei como fazer para direcionar para essa view, algumas coisas são criadas de forma automática e ainda não sei onde mexer.
Estou usando a versão 5.8 do laravel.

Alguém já passou por este problema e conhece a solução?

Comment: Você sabe qual é a controller responsável por fazer o controle dessas requisições?

Comment: Acredito que seja o arquivo de nome ResetPasswordController.php que fica no diretório App\Http\Controllers\Controllers\Auth. Porem não tem quase nada escrito nele.